# Hierarchies In JSON

Tags: json, firebase

I'm trying to create a database in Firebase...

I'd like to change this 'zero' level in this database to 'StudentsList' but have no idea how to do it:

[image]

Could someone please show me the syntax to change that root level of the JSON please?

This is what I currently have:

```
[ { "Gender" : "Male", "NameOfStd" : "Karachi Boi", "RollNo" : "10", "Section" : "b" } ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"StudentsList" : { "Gender" : "Male", "NameOfStd" : "Karachi Boi", "RollNo" : "10", "Section" : "b" } }
```

"[]" indicate an array (so with integer index) whilst "{}" indicate a dictionary.

if you want a list of student the answer should probably be :

```
{"StudentsList" : [{ "Gender" : "Male", "NameOfStd" : "Karachi Boi", "RollNo" : "10", "Section" : "b" }] }
```

which will give you this :

[image]